# How to set optional field in where clause query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, filter, where-clause

I have SQL query where I have to filter on bit field in some situations. If argument equals to an empty string then I should not include this bit field in my filter. Is there a goo way to do this with SQL Server 2008?
Here is example:

```
<cfargument name="masterActive" type="string" required="yes" default="">

<cfquery name="getRecords" datasource="#dsnRead#">
    DECLARE @ActiveFlag bit;
    SET @ActiveFlag = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.masterActive)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit">;

    SELECT tm_name, tm_comment, tm_active
    FROM Master WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE tm_tblid = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.masterTblid)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="15">
        AND tm_active = @ActiveFlag -- This field should be optional (if @ActiveFlag empty do not include tm_active in the filter)
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
AND tm_active = @ActiveFlag
```

add the following to your where clause:

```
AND (@ActiveFlag is null or tm_active = @ActiveFlag)
```

But be aware that parameter sniffing could lead to future performance problems.
See [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/).

Consider adding this instead

```
AND (@ActiveFlag is null or tm_active = @ActiveFlag) 
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@ActiveFlag UNKNOWN))
```